# Why does text surrounded by tildes in org mode turn grey

Tags: org-mode, syntax-highlighting

I noticed that text surrounded by tildes in org-mode turns grey (as least in my colour theme, and I assume the colour changes in others as well).  What is that about?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tildes are used for marking something as code/monospace. See [Emphasis and monospace](https://orgmode.org/manual/Emphasis-and-monospace.html#Emphasis-and-monospace) in the Org manual.

Your whole buffer might be monospace in Emacs (depending on your settings) so the gray is a useful distinction. If you were to publish the file as HTML that text would be surrounded by `<code>` tags.